# Passivform von "versprechen" mit "zu"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, passive, infinitive

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Selbstverständlich sei Moskau versprochen worden, die Nato-Truppen nicht “näher an das Territorium der ehemaligen Sowjetunion heranzurücken”

Wenn der Satz von der Aktivversion ersetzt wird, habe ich keinen Zweifel, dass es richtig ist.

> Selbstverständlich habe man Moskau versprochen, die Nato-Truppen nicht ... heranzurücken.

Aber die Passivversion klingt für mich seltsam. Schließlich geht Moskau nicht mit der Aktion vor, die Truppen heranzurücken. Moskau ist nur versprochen werden

Ist der Ausgangssatz richtig?

Man kann das mit dem Englischen vergleichen:

> He promised to do something. -> OK
>
> He was promised to do something -> Not OK

Comment: Ich finde "heranrücken" in diesem Kontext etwas komisch. "Die Nato rückt ihre Truppen näher an Russland heran." Das klingt etwas unbeholfen für meine Ohren. Wenn, dann rücken die Truppen selbst.

Comment: Also politisch betrachtet sollten die Tuppen bitte keinesfalls selbst rücken, sondern nur aufgrund eines Befehls gerückt werden - das Bild von Schachfiguren wird hier gern benutzt. Daher kann hier auch nur die politische Führung ein Versprechen abgeben, nicht die Truppen. Die physische Truppenbewegung - Soldat A bewegt sich (dann natürlich in der reflexiven Aktivform) in Richtung Ukraine ist nicht Gegenstand der Aussage im Beispiel des OP.

Comment: @Stephie.. macht Sinn. In der Praxis wird "[präfix]rücken" aber eher als aktives Verb verwendet "Die Truppe rückt vor." "Die Truppe ist bis auf 10 Kilometer an die Grenze herangerückt". "Die Truppe rückt aus." Ich kann allerdings keinerlei Beispiele für "[militärische Obrigkeit]rückt [Armee][irgendwohin]" finden. Deshalb denke ich, dass der Satz etwas unidiomatisch ist.

Comment: Durchaus idiomatisch. Zufälliges Beispiel: http://www.hintergrund.de/201407033142/politik/welt/wir-bewegen-truppen-israel-weitet-militaeroperation-aus.html

Comment: @Stephie... ich kann keine Instanz von "rücken" in diesem Text finden.

Comment: @Emanuel Ohne in eine Diskussion einsteigen zu wollen - Beispiel war für die aktiv / passiv Varianz. Mir persönlich gefällt die Wortwahl heranrücken, weil sie - im Kontext der politischen Berichterstattung - eine Formulierung aufgreift, die sonst als Begriff für politische Annäherung *positiv* belegt ist. Ob Zufall oder Absicht des Autors dahintersteckt, bleibt unklar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Vergleich mit dem Englischen täuscht hier.

> I gave him a boat.
>   He was given a boat by me.

Hier zeigt sich eine Besonderheit des Passivs in Englisch. Man kann das indirekte Objekt des Aktivs zum Subjekt des Passivs machen. Das ist in Deutsch nicht möglich. Dativ bleibt Dativ. Nur das direkte Objekt kann das Subjekt des Passivs werden.

> Ich habe ihm ein Boot gegeben.
>   Ihm wurde ein Boot von mir gegeben.
>   *Er wurde ein Boot gegeben … sehr, sehr falsch

Nimmt man den Satz der Frage (verändert), so sieht man große Unterschiede:

> Martin (ihm) wurde versprochen, etwas zu tun.
>   *Martin (he) was promised to do something.

Im Englischen ist "Martin" das Subjekt und "to do something" müsste die Position eines Objekts haben. Das geht.

> I try [what? A soup/to do something].

Allerdings ist in einer "to"-Konstruktion das Subjekt das gleiche wie im Hauptsatz. Im "to do something"-Teil wäre Martin also Agens. Und das kollidiert mit dem Sinn, was meiner Meinung nach der Grund dafür sein könnte, warum es nicht funktioniert. 
In Deutsch ist das nicht so ein Problem, da "Martin" eben genau NICHT das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes ist. Er ist Rezipient und hat somit mit dem Subjekt der zu-Konstruktion nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 3):

Beide Sätze sind korrekt und klingen für mich nicht seltsam. In beiden Fällen bleibt ohne Zusammenhang bzw. Hintergrundwissen zunächst offen, wer das Versprechen abgegeben hat bzw. haben soll. Auch die Bedeutung ist fast gleich, nur steht der erste Satz im Konjunktiv ("sei"), so dass es sich lediglich um die Wiedergabe einer Behauptung (Zitat) handeln könne, während der zweite Satz selbst die Behauptung darstellt.

EDIT:

In beiden Sätzen soll das Versprechen an Moskau abgegeben worden sein. In den genannten englischen Vergleichssätzen wird jedoch Geber und Nehmer des Versprechens vertauscht. Analog müsste es heißen:

> He was promised that something is being done.
>
> Someone promised him that something is being done.

oder mit to do:

> Someone promised him to do something.

Der Satz "Ihm ist versprochen worden, etwas zu tun." hört sich schon im Deutschen schräg an (das liegt aber an "etwas zu tun") und funktioniert im Englischen mit "He was promised to do" gar nicht (Deinem "Not OK" stimme ich hier also zu).

Comment: Jemand, dem nur etwas versprochen worden ist und dem offenbar niemand etwas versprochen hat, kann sich dann auch bei niemandem beschweren, wenn das Versprechen nicht eingehalten wurde. Das Passiv wird oft verwendet, wenn es keine greifbaren Handelnden gibt, aber auch, wenn man die Handlung selbst hervorheben will.